# Updating and deleting one record within object

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a system in which I can display, edit and delete information on players and teams using angular along with a RESTful API. I have the parts working in which I show all the data and post data to the database.

The part I am having trouble with is updating data as I can't manage to get the http put working with the correct data being sent.

HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="team-single.html">
    <div class="team-box">
        <div class="badge">
            <img ng-src="images/{{x.club_name}}.png" width="100" height="100"></div>


<div ng-hide="editorEnabled">
  <div class="team-name">{{x.club_name}}</div>
        <p><b>Manager:</b> {{x.club_manager}}</p>
        <p><b>Ground:</b> {{x.club_ground}}</p>
        <p><b>Nickname:</b> {{x.club_nickname}}</p>
        <div class="team-p">{{x.club_info}}</div>
  <a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled">Edit Team</a>
</div>
<div ng-show="editorEnabled">
    <p><input ng-model="x.club_name"></p>
    <p><input ng-model="x.club_manager"></p>
    <p><input ng-model="x.club_ground"></p>
    <p> <input ng-model="x.club_nickname"></p>
    <p><input ng-model="x.club_info"></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" ng-value="" />
  <a href="#" ng-click="editorEnabled=!editorEnabled; updateTeam($index)">Save</a>
        </div>

</script>

<div class="row teams">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="x in teams" ng-include="'team-single.html'"></div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('footballApp', []);

app.controller("TeamCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.updateTeam = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'clubs.php/teams/' + id,
        data: ??,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
   });
};
});
```

I have enabled an editor on the front end to edit the fields.  I don't know how to pass the one object being edited back into the updateTeam function while not passing the entire team array.

Also in the HTTP PUT, I have to use the id field of the relevant club in the URL but I'm not sure how to send this back.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can add [ngChnage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) to initiate the update function after changes, or [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) for changes indide the model

Comment: PUT puts a file or resource at a specific URI. POST sends data to a specific URI and expects the resource at that URI to handle the request. You likely want POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you might need to rethink your UI. Why do you want to show edit option for all teams at once in the UI. Ideally you should show the team details along with an option to edit them.

When user click on `edit` call a function with `team` data and then show a form where those details can be edited and later can be send for submission.

Refer to this plnkr example https://plnkr.co/edit/muqnmIhO77atLyEHS9y7?p=preview

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4" ng-repeat="team in teams">
    <h2>{{ team.club_name }}</h2>
    <p>{{ team.club_info }}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onEditDetails(team)" href="javascript:void(0);" role="button">Edit details »</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

and then in controller

```
$scope.onEditDetails = function(team) {
    $scope.team = team;
};
```

This will give you the reference of current selected team. You can use `$scope.team` then to show a `form` in UI which can be submitted along with its new edited data.

**Note:** In your example you are using a template to show HTML in UI but since they are in a `ng-repeat` each of your template will be using the `last` variable of loop. A template included using `ng-include` doesn't create a different scope for each of your `team` in `teams`.

If you want to create reusable HTML (though un-necessary as per your requirement) you can create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and include it in your `ng-repeat` as `<my-team-directive data="x"></my-team-directive>`

Comment: Great. This is a good idea and it works! Just one problem though.. When opening the edit box, it always shows the final team, rather than the relevant team that has been clicked..

Comment: Are you referring to shared plnkr link or while implementing in your code?

Comment: While implementing my code.  I think it may because I am using templates

Comment: i have edited the answer to explain why it is showing last item always. check the **Note** part.

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much for your help!